# solution for combining db fields and multiple word docs into a single printable format

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

For a project that I'm working on, I need to do a one click "print all" feature that will allow my users to do a printable view of several database fields, combined with 2 word documents that are stored as blob data in database.  I've looked at using the openxml library, but it was having trouble opening up some of my word docs.  I was also looking at using crystal reports, but I'm not terribly familiar with crystal I haven't found any good examples on how to include word docs from blob storage.

So I'm looking for suggestions on the best way to go about doing this.  Are the options that I've already looked into the best options?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't a lot of money for operating with some commercial libraries, like [Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) , and you don't like openxml library at all. Then, in my opinion, your best choice is laying in some low-level stuff. Just take into account that any openxml document is just a .zip archive. So, you should uncompressed it, and inside this package look up for a *word* folder where you should define *document.xml* file. It will contain your document itself. Further, you should just parse this xml to find out your data.